# Rollup Column for Normalized Sums (SQL) - Part 1

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table like so:

```
object_id | vote
1 | 2
1 | -1
1 | 5
2 | 3
2 | 1
3 | 4
3 | -2
```

I want this result (for this particular example, object_ids 1 and 2 are part of a group, defined elsewhere, and I'm looking for the normalized_score so that the sum always = 1.  object_id 3 is part of an unused group.):

```
object_id | normalized_score
1 | 6/10
2 | 4/10
```

[added 3:05PM] 10 here is the sum of the votes for object_id in (1,2).  There's a whole other set of logic to come up with the (1,2), I was just trying to give the cleanest question so people don't have to worry about that part.

[added 3:10PM] As pointed out in the comments, if the score for one of the objects is below 0, a problem arises.  Here is the rule, "IF the score for any outcome_id is -x, AND that is the minimum score for the set, ADD x to all scores in order to zero-out the minimum score".  I can do this on my own time though outside of SQL - so it's a bonus only if somebody has the cahones to try to tackle it in SQL.

If I do a self join, I can get the sum.  I can't figure out how to get the normalized sum.  Ideally this will work in both MySQL 5.x and Sqlite3.  Otherwise, I can do this with two separate queries and just do the work in post-processing.

Comment: Where does the "10" come into things here?

Comment: If the vote is supposed to be out of 10 then how can you allow negative votes?

Comment: I'm sorry 10 is the sum of votes where object_id in (1,2).  I'll update the question

Comment: Negative scores would zero out.  The way the app works, it would be extremely rare for that to ever happen - although I will come up with a more robust addendum to the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution without compensating for negative votes (I include this one because its much easier to read/understand):

```
SELECT object_id
,      SUM(vote) + '/' + total AS normalized_score
FROM   tabel
,      (
       SELECT sum(vote) AS total
       FROM   tabel
       ) 
GROUP BY object_id, total
```

Full solution:

```
SELECT object_id
,      SUM(vote + minvote) + '/' + (total + minvote * count) AS normalized_score
FROM   tabel
,      (
       SELECT sum(vote) AS total
       ,      CASE WHEN MIN(vote) < 0 THEN
                  -MIN(vote)
              END AS minvote
       ,      COUNT(*) AS count
       FROM   tabel
       ) 
GROUP BY object_id, total, minvote, count
```

(I don't have access to MySQL, so I wrote a query in Oracle and replaced || for +. Hope it works in MySQL or at least helps :))

Comment: Yeah - I was thinking a subquery was necessary.  I usually try to avoid those, and I'm sure there's a non subquery solution, but that should be good enough for fewer than a few hundred thousand records - which is fine for now.  Thanks for a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are quite correct.. but I'll make the assumption that 10 is just some number you picked out of your... nose.

SELECT object_id AS ObjectID, SUM(vote) + '/10' AS NormalizedVote
FROM table
GROUP BY object_id

Enjoy.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear.  '10' is the sum of all the other votes in that group - otherwise this would be a trivial question.  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- SQL solution
SELECT 
  object_id AS ObjectID, 
  (SUM(CASE SIGN(vote) WHEN 1 THEN vote ELSE 0 END) - 
    ((CASE SIGN(MIN(vote)) WHEN -1 THEN MIN(vote) ELSE 0) * 
     (COUNT(1)))) + '/10' AS NormalizedVote
FROM table 
GROUP BY object_id
```

Comment: Similarly to the one I marked as the answer (although that one is fixable), the SUM() includes the votes for object_id=3, which won't work.  I like that there's no subquery though - thanks for the input.